# Symfony + Doctrine: Strange parameters injection in the action method

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using Symfony and Doctrine in my project. And I noticed one strange (for me) thing.

I have simple action in my controller:

```
    /**
     * @param Request      $request
     * @param Product|null $product
     *
     * @Config\Route("/{category}/create", name="my_project_create_product")
     * @Config\Route("/{category}/edit/{product}", name="my_project_edit_product")
     * @Config\Template()
     *
     * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function createEditAction(Request $request, ProductCategory $category, Product $product = null)
```

The product parameter is optional and using only for edit action as you can see in my annotation.

The problem is that when I use url /{category}/create it somehow injects the product object (it's the first product in my collection with the given category). However, the **product parameter expected to be null**.

**The question is how the product parameter injects by itself if I don't pass it to url?**

P.S The product has the reference to category. And this only happens if I use the category parameter in the method.

Symfony version 3.3.4

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigations and debugging I actually found the solution to that problem.

I really didn't know that ParamConverter "will attempt to do a findOneBy() fetch by using all of the wildcards in your route that are actually properties on your entity (non-properties are ignored)". ([source link](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)). So if it doesn't find by id (primary key) it will tries to search by criteria. There are some ways to fix that (and all options could be found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#paramconverter-options)). However, I chose to exclude the category from product mapping:

```
 /**
 * @param Request      $request
 * @param Product|null $product
 *
 * @Config\Route("/{category}/create", name="my_project_create_product")
 * @Config\Route("/{category}/edit/{product}", name="my_project_edit_product")
 * @Config\ParamConverter("product", options={"exclude": {"category"}})
 * @Config\Template()
 *
 * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function createEditAction(Request $request, ProductCategory $category, Product $product = null)
```

Actually, this line "**@Config\ParamConverter("product", options={"exclude": {"category"}})**" solves the entire issue.

Hope, this will help someone and will save some time.